# Superselection rules and Hilbert space decomposition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space

I was reading [Superselection Sectors, Klaus Fredenhagen](https://unith.desy.de/e27292/e27308/e78138/e78256/e78257/infoboxContent78269/superselect.pdf) and in the introduction it states

> "The existence of superselection rules leads to the following picture of the quantum mechanical state space: The Hilbert space of quantum mechanical state vectors is a direct sum of orthogonal subspaces".

Physically it makes sense to me, but is there a way to prove it mathematically?

EDIT:

More specifically, I want to prove that the existence of superselection rule allows to separate the Hilbert space $H$ in a direct sum of subspaces $H_i$ with well defined eigenvalues.

Comment: A Hilbert space is a vector space, and a vector space enables you to create an orthogonal basis. "Using" this basis, the direct sum of those leads to subspaces which are orthogonal to each other if the aforementioned basis vectors are orthogonal.

disclaimer: I'm not a mathematician. Also, imho it's common sense in this context and I wouldn't assign too much importance to the statement.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I just edited the question, hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: What is your definition of "superselection rule" here? One might *define* "superselection rule" as the existence of the $H_i$, in which case there is nothing to prove.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: @Joel, as I said, this separation property is fulfilled by Hilbert space by itself. You can introduce eigenvalues by solving *any* eigenvalue problem. "Superselection" is not necessary for this.

Comment: Oh, I see now I was a bit confused.